# Postgres grouping values together instead of having individual values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I have written this code below and I want to produce something that looks similar to this:

```
Days Before Stay  | Number of Submits
-------------------------------------
0-9        |        11
10-19      |        14
20-29      |         3
```

I have create a select case statement which creates a syntax error

```
WITH sql_runner_query AS (SELECT 
events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay' AS "Number of Days 
Before Stay",
COUNT(CASE WHEN ((events_raw.properties ->> 'event_type') LIKE 
'fs_mystay_activity_submit') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Number of 
Activities Processed"
FROM events_raw

WHERE (events_raw.account_id  = 7270737) AND 
((((events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay') IS NOT NULL) AND 
((events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay') IS NOT NULL AND 
LENGTH(events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay') <> 0 ))) AND 
(events_raw.account_id  > 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 desc 
LIMIT 500
)

(SELECT 
 events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay' AS "Number of Days 
Before Stay",
COUNT(CASE WHEN ((events_raw.properties ->> 'event_type') LIKE 
'fs_mystay_activity_submit') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Number of 
Activities Processed"
 case when 'days_before_stay' >= 0 and <=10 then '0-10'
 else
'11-300' end as range
FROM events_raw

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 5000
```

Comment: You need to share the error message, and explain how it relates to your question title.  Also, the CTE sql_runner_query isn't requested at all in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT` in the 2nd part of the query shouldn't have a `(`

You are missing a comma here:

`COUNT(CASE WHEN ((events_raw.properties ->> 'event_type') LIKE 
'fs_mystay_activity_submit') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Number of 
Activities Processed"
,  -- add a comma here
 case when 'days_before_stay' >= 0 and <=10 then '0-10'
 else '11-300' end as range`

Other issues with the query:

- why are you grouping by the COUNT()?
- why do you have a CTE called sql_runner_query and then not reference it in the main query?